# × Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i'm currently working on a rails api to work with my js website and I keep getting this error `Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0` when trying to post data to the server.

I was wondering if anyone can help me fix this. The error is located here in my code.

```
    }
     } catch(errors) {
      //error is on this line below
       let formErrors = JSON.parse(errors);
       let errorsArray = [];
      for(var key in formErrors) {
```

Comment: It might make sense to include the json, no? Maybe even the controller. I'd guess there's something wrong with your json...

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry for the lack of documentation. But i'm trying to post data through a form, to my server and display the array of errors on the page. It works on react native but not in a regular reactjs website.

Comment: Neat. Without context nobody will be able to help.

Comment: In `JSON.parse(errors)`, might rails app return `errors` as a standard string (some thing like "The record not found") instead of json string format ("{'key': 'value'}")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding out that rack cors was not set up in my rails project. So if anyone has this problem. Just configure rack cors in:

`config/application.rb`

And paste this:

```
 config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```